# Unresolved reference: pagerTabIndicatorOffset

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, pager, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm pretty new to jetpack and am following [this](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-tabs-with-jetpack-compose/) guide.

When trying to create my tabs I'm hitting an `UnresolvedReference` and I'm not sure why

```kotlin
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun Tabs(tabs: List<TabItem>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
        contentColor = Color.White,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
            )
        }) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
            LeadingIconTab(
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                text = { Text(tab.title) },
                icon = { Icon(painter = painterResource(id = tab.icon), contentDescription = "") },
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
```

Everything else work. I have `implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.28.0")` in my `build.gradle` and am importing

Did I miss an import or library somewhere? `androidx.compose.ui.Modifier` in the class itself. I know I saw elsewhere that was a common Modifier problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a separate one that you have to specify in your dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.27.1'
```

I removed mine and same error shown
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Starting of Jetpack Compose 1.4.0-alpha03 there is a native `HorizontalPager`. `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager` which you don't have to use pagerTabIndicatorOffset.

Sample

```
@Composable
private fun HomeContent() {

    val pagerState: PagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    TabRow(
     
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage
    ) {
        // Add tabs for all of our pages
        tabList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(title) },
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        pageCount = tabList.size,
        beyondBoundsPageCount = 3
    ) { page: Int ->

        when (page) {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Thracian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457853/thracian) has indicated above, both `com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager` and `Indicator` have since been [deprecated](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) in favor of `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager`.

> This library is deprecated, with official pager support in
> androidx.compose.foundation.pager. The original documentation is below
> the migration guide.

On Material 3 the Accompanist's `Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset()` function is now **`Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset()`** as shown below:

```
//the Tab and TabRow should import from material3
import androidx.compose.material3.Tab
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults.tabIndicatorOffset

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerItem() {

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0, pageCount = { 5 })
val tabs = listOf(...)


TabRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage])
                )
            }

    ) {

        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tabItem ->

            Tab(selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) } },
                    content = { ....}
```